# Disable model saves not going though DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to disable model saves unless the data is coming via a DRF serializer.
I'm not sure the best way to do this. 
One way i can think of is override the save method and add some check which is fulfilled by the data coming from drf.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That might be the simplest approach. But it might be possible that anyone else can pass the same data to the model save. Why do you want to restrict it?

Comment: I want to put a layer on top of the models and want to restrict direct access to the data from the model, so I can control the input and output. It is a very specialised case and the whole thing will not be publicly exposed. 
Also I want all data to be validated, which does not happen with clean since it is only called when coming via a form